# how to store methods in a hash table?

Tags: c#, object, methods, hashtable

I am trying to store a list of methods in a hash table in C# so I am able to preform the method as soon at the user enter the key required. I was wondering how I would do this. I have been told i can use both anonymous interfaces or delegates to do this. which is better and why? I have not been able to find much reference to how this would actually done though.

Example:

key = method

"+" = object.add

"-" = object.minus

Comment: check [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) and [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: In 2017 you shouldn't use an `Hashtable`, you should use a `Dictionary<string, yourdelegatetype>`

Answer (score 5):

This is an over-simplified solution, but it illustrates the steps necessary to accomplish your requirement.

```
public class Test
{
    // Ok, we declare the hashtable here. It could be a Dictionary though, so we don't have to
    // cast it. But you requested a hashtable.
    private Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();

    // Were it a dictionary, we'd have:
    // private Dictionary<string, Calculation> dict = new Dictionary<string, Calculation>();

    // We declare the signature of the methods that we will store. This means that we accept any
    // methods which receive two decimal parameters and return a decimal output
    private delegate decimal Calculation(decimal x, decimal y);

    public Test()
    {
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        // A sample implementation of the delegate
        Calculation sum = (decimal x, decimal y) =>
        {
            return x + y;
        };

        // Another sample implementation
        Calculation minus = (decimal x, decimal y) =>
        {
            return x - y;
        };

        // Here we add both of them to the hashtable
        this.hash.Add("+", sum);
        this.hash.Add("-", minus);

        // Were it a dictionary, we'd have:
        // this.dict.Add("+", sum);
        // this.dict.Add("+", minus);

        // Note that in the hashtable you can put ANYTHING. Were it a dictionary, it would be strong-typed and
        // we'd be able to only add Calculation types

        // Now ask the user for input values
        Console.Write("X: ");
        var xInput = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Y: ");
        var yInput = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // Ask the user which method to execute
        Console.WriteLine("Which method to execute? Enter number:");
        Console.WriteLine("1. +");
        Console.WriteLine("2. -");
        Console.Write("> ");

        var choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // Get the selected method from the hashtable
        Calculation calc;
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            calc = (Calculation)this.hash["+"];
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            calc = (Calculation)this.hash["-"];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        // Were it a dictionary, we'd have (note that we don't have to cast it):
        // calc = this.dict["-"];

        // execute it, and output the result
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + calc(xInput, yInput));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# to store method reference there is a type called Delegate. You should use dictionary of delegates. First you must define a delegate that matchs your methods' signatures. Imagine you have the list of methods that returns `int` and accept two `int` as a parameter.First you define delegate for that.

```
 public delegate int SomeMethodsHandler(int a,int b);
```

And then you create your methods.

```
public int MethodA(int a,int b)
{
      // do some work here
      return 0;
}

 public int MethodB(int a,int b)
{
      // do some work here
      return 1;
}

 public int MethodC(int a,int b)
{
      // do some work here
      return 2;
}
```

And then you create Dictionary to store that methods.

```
 Dictionary<string,SomeMethodsHandler> methods = new Dictionary<string,SomeMethodsHandler>();

 methods["A"] = MethodA;
 methods["B"] = MethodB;
 methods["C"] = MethodC;
```

And again to invoke that methods.

```
 int a = methods["A"](5,7);
```

Comment: nice .. can you please tell **HOW** and **WHEN** this type of invocation is helpful?

Comment: Question here is how methods can be stored in key value pair structure. What about your quesition is that i never come accross that kind of sitaution where i need to store method reference in dictionary. But delegates by itself are very useful when you need to implement observer patterns or doing some kind of functional stuff.